# What is the difference between these two queries(Using IN and JOIN)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to find whatever the matching records(NPI) are there in both. I tried with both below queries. But both are giving different results in count (Say 12000 and 200000 respectively). 
Between:

```
SELECT * FROM Emblem_Attested 
WHERE NPINUMBER IN (SELECT NPINUMBER FROM Empire_Attested)
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM Empire_Attested emp JOIN Emblem_Attested emb ON emp.NPINUMBER = emb.NPINUMBER
```

I don't know which one is correct.

Comment: Both are correct..but different as one uses join and other without

Comment: Then why result is different? It should be same, isn't it.

Comment: If you only want unique you can user select distinct *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IN` clause will only give you the rows in `Emblem_Attested` that have an `NPINUMBER` in `Empire_Attested`. If there are records in `Emblem_Attested` with the same `NPINUMBER` this will not affect the result.

For example, if `Emblem_Attested` has an `NPINUMBER` of `1` and the `Empire_Arrested` table has multiple records with an `NPINUMBER` of `1`. Then only one record will be returned with an `NPINUMBER` of `1`.

The `JOIN` will give you more record if there are multiple records in `Emblem_Attested` with the same `NPINUMBER`. If there are duplicate NPINUMBER in `Emblem_Attested` then you will get more records in your results from the `JOIN`. This is what you are seeing.

With the `JOIN`, if `Emblem_Attested` has an `NPINUMBER` of `1` and the `Empire_Arrested` table has multiple records with an `NPINUMBER` of `1`. Then multiple records will be returned as the join will return a record for each record in `Empire_Arrested` with an `NPINUMBER` of `1`.

Comment: Means if duplicates are there then it will return those duplicates too...?

Comment: @vic yes, if you are joining on NPINUMBER and there are duplicates in NPINUMBER it will return a record for each duplicate NPINUMBER.

Answer (score 0):

They look different for one thing.

There are two big differences.  The second gets columns from both tables, and the first only from `Emblem_Attested`.

Another difference is that the `JOIN` will return multiple rows if there are duplicates in `Empire_Attested`.  The `IN` will not return such duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

The first query will return all the records of `Emblem_Attested` that it's `NPINUMBER` exists in table `Empire_Attested`.

The second one will return all the records of both tables where they have the same value in `NPINUMBER` column, meaning that you will get a recordset that contains the columns of both tables. Also, if any `NPINUMBER` of `Empire_Attested` appears more then once in `Emblem_Attested` you will get a record for each value in `Emblem_Attested`, with duplicated data on the columns of `Emblem_Attested`.

Answer (score 0):

Joins will duplicate the parent rows (Empire_Attested?) if many child rows (Empire_Attested?) are present.
The IN query will return a single parent row.
I'd be looking for more than one entry on the Empire_Attested table.

You should see it with the following query

```
SELECT NPINUMBER, COUNT(*) Qty 
FROM Empire_Attested 
GROUP BY NPINumber
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```